# Components listen to data in parent

Tags: vue.js

See https://jsfiddle.net/d017am59/1/

I have a checkbox controling whether `box` elements should show text in black.

```html
<div id="app">
<label><input type='checkbox' v-model='showBlack' />Show black</label>

<box>Hello</box>
<box>World</box>
<box>Hi</box>
<box>Bye</box>
</div>
```

```js
Vue.component('box', {
  template: `
    <div v-bind:style='styleObject'>
      {{text}}
      <slot></slot>
    </div>`,
  data: function() {
    return {
      text: vueApp.showBlack?'black text: ':'white text: ',
      styleObject:{
            color: vueApp.showBlack?'black':'white',
            'background-color':vueApp.showBlack?'white':'black',
      }
    }
  }
});

const vueApp= new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showBlack: true,
  },
});
```

`box` is a complicated component, but I only present the relavent props here. For illustration, if the checkbox is checked, the color is black, the background is white; if the checkbox is unchecked, the color and the background color is reversed.

My code doesn't work because Vue throws an error `"Cannot access 'vueApp' before initialization."`

How do my `box` elements listen to the checkbox?

I don't like using a global mixin so much because a global mixin is going to inject to all components, where I only want to inject to `box`.

I don't like adding a prop to box, and pass `showBlack` to the prop of all `box` instances. My business requirement is ALL boxes must obey the checkbox, and it is cumbersome and error-prone if I have to write:

```html
<box v-bind:showBlack="showBlack">Hello</box>
<box v-bind:showBlack="showBlack">Wolrd</box>
<box v-bind:showBlack="showBlack">Hi</box>
<box v-bind:showBlack="showBlack">Bye</box>
```

I'm fine to use Vue 2 or 3.

Comment: I think you can try using Vuex where you can maintain the state that whether you want to display in black or white.

Comment: If it’s just styles that are changed, you can use the :checked pseudo class in css. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/

Comment: @GavinBruce No, there is `{{text}}` changing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution is to use [`this.$root`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-root) to access the data of the root instance (the one that instantiates `Vue`). Also, note the bindings in `<box>` should be to [`computed` props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) so that they're reactive to changes in the root's `showBlack`:

```js
Vue.component('box', {
  template: `
    <div v-bind:style='styleObject'>
      {{ text }}
      <slot></slot>
    </div>`,
  computed: {
    text() {
      return this.$root.showBlack ? 'black text: ' : 'white text: '
    },
    styleObject() {
      return {
        color: this.$root.showBlack ? 'black' : 'white',
        'background-color': this.$root.showBlack ? 'white' : 'black',
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/MWbpKqe?editors=1010)

Comment: How can I miss this property. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

HTML:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div><label><input type='checkbox' v-model='showBlack' />Show black</label></div>
  <box :black="showBlack">Hello</box>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
Vue.component('box', {
  template: `
    <div v-bind:style='styleObject'>
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  `,
  props: ['black'],
  data: function() {
    return {}
  },
  computed: {
    styleObject() {
      return { 
        color: this.black ? 'black' : 'white',
        'background-color': this.black ? 'white' : 'black',
      }
    }
  }
});


const vueApp= new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showBlack: true,
  },
});
```